# Never pass long long as a parameter?

Tags: c++, long-integer

The programming question is:

> given a grid of numbers, how many distinct primes can you find embedded in the matrix, regarding that you can read the lines or part of them, in form vertical, horizontal or diagonal orientation, in both directions?

BIG EDIT: For any poor soul reading this, I solved this by adding `if (n > INT_MAX) return false;` to the first line under my function!

My program does not crash as long as the parameter to `isPrime` is not `const ll &n` and I wonder why. Is it because you are never supposed to pass `long long` as a parameter because it's so large? Or is it because if you add an `int` to a `long long` integer, it no longer becomes a `long long`?

The input I am using to test my work is:

```
40
0251677085866837460317708637021446063144
8812262220360202463050064531874436437682
5251855367278508848642345043775871434078
0042675865438283025822603307175060748288
5672321632434878440388701468545837465571
3448326728143606881852187616524878044060
8876415778774852362710315274652021065556
1406474838287088561242126854006826771778
7827443331184330371521043472218803550383
6318874838447276075161123302780187880165
0884752758538865306583258450386821283658
1260362124615176735303563717773657467333
2580363145201308707655341168610513145546
4142635386876777348215436708254351251288
5301330463217260626047132625527161775404
8620446353006857360714856156584322276288
0813375760405334773480860674772272733638
6715558007108501053612008324501255710425
8840634327383685827335506853781648727036
8827728873376824454871536655067801443735
0664640563836487481174816586572628815173
7186752536147276768154002317573417465332
4438770023402783205544064640821537621225
4162442401558771474140203865162080237721
5008757506737224070577338578644664641338
2155803687408638660278862273674652462840
2118148017744113203720114756276821067158
4838003412436782114402742024145245437315
5161343527676283186170466281455700086618
7723886261287175705152273086317588317188
6653360024271146551000054710768617586846
0050014847531086708661266564560614115164
3351156208161708784441387827072734346251
0457546342466313073230326436563643506534
3837451141488371231210888733717540046582
3334248265835234158638343058444640886465
0173240266426385002380821305357684721128
0437020214873361352055818843664073456138
3858604586068245520287541000014334760058
5840781588142205318614583635575571714673
```

My code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

typedef long long ll;

const int DIRECTIONS[][2] = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, 1}};

bool isPrime(const int &n) {
        if (n != 2) {
                if (n < 2 || !(n & 1)) return false;
                for (ll i = 3; i * i <= n + 1; i += 2) {
                        if (n % i == 0) return false;
                }
        }
        return true;
}

int main() {
        int length = 0;
        std::set<ll> primes{};
        char c;
        std::cin >> length;
        std::vector<std::vector<ll>> grid;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                std::vector<ll> row;
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                        std::cin >> c;
                        row.push_back(c - '0');
                }
                grid.push_back(row);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                        for (auto d : DIRECTIONS) {
                                int tempi = i, tempj = j;
                                ll base10 = 0;
                                while (i < length && j < length && i >= 0 && j >= 0) {
                                        base10 *= 10;
                                        base10 += grid[i][j];
                                        if (isPrime(base10)) primes.insert(base10);
                                        i += d[0];
                                        j += d[1];
                                }
                                i = tempi;
                                j = tempj;
                        }
                }
        }
        std::cout << "Number of primes: " << primes.size() << std::endl;
        /*std::cout << "List of primes: " << std::flush;
        for (auto prime : primes) {
                std::cout << prime << " " << std::flush;
        }*/
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int grid[length][length];` is not allowed in Standard C++

Comment: @M.M it compiles correctly in codeblocks? Is it not supposed to compile?

Comment: It relies on non-standard extensions

Comment: @BoWork think on what happens if you supply say, 10,000,000,000 as length. That's a whole hell of a lot of Automatic storage space used up. Bets you don't have more than 10,000,000 bytes.

Comment: the loop `for (ll i = 3; i * i <= n + 1; i += 2) {` will cause undefined behaviour if `n` is a large prime. the `i * i` may overflow

Comment: @user4581301 I'll be using a vector and will repost again if I still have a problem. thanks

Comment: @M.M Yeah, so I want to change `n` to be a long long. Theoretically that should fix the undefined behaviour because then `i` and `n` will both be long longs. But that crashes the program and I wonder why.

Comment: @BoWork your change introduces the undefined behaviour because if `n` is only an `int` then `i*i` can never get big enough to overflow

Comment: @BoWork "*But that crashes the program and I wonder why*" - that is what a debugger is good for figuring out.

Comment: speed tweak: take advantage of `reserve`ing  space in the `vector`s. Saves on resizing.

Comment: I recommend investing some time finding better ways to determine primality. This approach repeats a huge amount of work on every iteration.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, I am trying the Miller Rabin because this is such a headache.

Comment: An interesting idea, but memoization may work better for you. If you've found all the primes up to 900 while testing for 900, there's no point to checking anything under 900 and next time you have a number over 900 you can start at 900 and work upwards from there.

Comment: anyway the code obviously causes undefined behaviour in computing `base10` since it exceeds max value for long long

Comment: @user4581301 That gives me inspiration to get a text file of the first 2000 primes and check if a supposed prime is in there.

Comment: you'll need a big text file if you intend to validate a 40-digit prime that way

Comment: Yeah. Normally I'd say use a sieve, but 10 to the 40... Yow!

Comment: I still can't quite wrap my head around the crash. Tonnes of wrong answers, yes but crashes no.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't get it either, since just changing the data type to int makes the program run in a few seconds, but the other way takes infinite amount of time.

Comment: `int` has a much MUCH smaller search space than a `long long` If the function can only search up to 2 billion it's going to take a lot less time than the function that has to scan  up to 9 quadrillion. 9 Quintillion? I lose track that high up.

Comment: @user4581301 that might actually be the right answer. I just implemented the miller rabin (with 1000 iterations!) and this leads to the same results when switching parameters from int to long long.

Comment: That's the idea I'm bashing around above: You do not want to compute every time. Just finding one prime number gives you enough information to find all of the primes beneath it. If this is an ACM programming problem, even that's going to be too slow. There will be some damn-sneaky trick to eliminate 90% or more of the work. You either know the trick or you better pray you can figure it out if you want to answer the problem in the allotted time. The fact that you can't get numbers big enough in a conventional computer just hammers home that there's some trick involved.

Comment: Some of the primes were negative, so therein lies the source of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program causes undefined behaviour in the part with:

```
base10 *= 10;
base10 += grid[i][j]
```

because those computations exceed the maximum value of `long long` sometimes.

The `long long` might not hold more than 19 decimal digits. If the intent is to validate primes of up to 40 digits then you will have to switch to a different approach.